# Need to count how many specific hours are within 2 timeframes

Tags: if-statement, time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to make a time registration for employees.
I have made a Google Forms that the employees will register start date&time and end date&time in this format:

```
Employee X  |  10/6/2019 12:00:00  |  10/6/2019 20:00:00
```

This is 3 cells in Google Sheets.

The employees need to get payed x more when they work between the hours 18:00 & 06:00 in the morning.
So I need a formula that takes the start time and end time of their shift and counts how many of the shift hours that fall between 18:00 & 06:00 and returns the amount of hours that they have worked in this frame.

In the above example, Employee X has worked from 12:00 til 20:00, an 8-hour total workday.

BUT the formula needs to return how many of those hours that are between 18:00 & 06:00 eg. 2 hours. in a cell of its own.

I have tried all sorts of `COUNTIFS`, `FILTER` and other stuff, but this one I cannot solve.

Does anyone have the magic touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should cover it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(
 (IF(DATEVALUE(C1:C)>DATEVALUE(B1:B), 1, 0)+TIMEVALUE(C1:C)>0.75)*
 (IF(DATEVALUE(C1:C)=DATEVALUE(B1:B), 1, 0)+0.25>TIMEVALUE(C1:C)), 
 TEXT((0.75-TIMEVALUE(C1:C))*-1, "hh:mm:ss"), )))
```

[image: 0]

---

**note:** `0.75` = 18:00:00 and `0.25` = 6:00:00

Comment: That works like a charm!
Thank you SO much, would never have thought of that myself :)